How to run bleachbit on fedora proot-distro
I'm trying to clean up my fedora on my android because the size got too big, then i'm trying to use bleachbit but I got an error
`
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/usr/bin/bleachbit", line 40, in <module>
    bleachbit.Unix.is_display_protocol_wayland_and_root_not_allowed()
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Unix.py", line 746, in is_display_protocol_wayland_and_root_not_allowed
    bleachbit.Unix.is_linux_display_protocol_wayland() and
    ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/share/bleachbit/Unix.py", line 732, in is_linux_display_protocol_wayland
    session = result[1].split('\n')[1].strip().split(' ')[0]
              ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~^^^
IndexError: list index out of range

Can anyone help me to make it run on my fedora proot-distro, or something that can help to clean my storage issue?
